# Interactive shell via telnet

Tags: terminal, telnet, tty, socat

My plan is to offer a route-server, which is a small interactive program, via telnet to the world. Like this: telnet://route-server.he.net

As a minimal example, I'd start with a simple bash, offered via socat:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9001,reuseaddr,crnl,fork EXEC:bash,pty,stderr,sane,setsid,sigint,echo=0
```

Now I connect using telnet:

```
$ telnet localhost 9001
```

And it seems to work at first:

```
$ echo foo
foo
```

The problem is: some special characters like ESC, arrow keys, etc. are printed as their shell escape codes. Example for 'arrow up':

```
$ ^[[A
foo
```

Also, clicking/scrolling/... prints escape codes, too:

```
$ ^[[M r>^[[M#r>
```

The question is: how can I fix this behaviour in a way that clients can continue using telnet without any client side options or hacks, as it does on existing route-servers out there.

Comment: Use in.telnetd, which already offers interactive shell. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on ipors comment we managed to run the service with following setup:

xinetd runs telnetd from GNU Inetutils (ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/inetutils/)

```
server = /path/to/custom/telnetd
```

In the server_args, we defined an exec-String which points to a wrapper-script to run our birdc with the required options

```
server_args = -h -E "/opt/bird-telnet.sh"
```

/opt/bird-telnet.sh looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/birdc -r -s /var/run/bird/bird.ctl
```